# Misconfiguration of master.cf or main.cf

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have folishly played around with master.cf and main.cf without creating a backup first on postfix and somehow managed to make it so I can't send or receive e-mails anymore.
I'm getting the following error when running

```
root@mail:/etc/postfix# tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep "smtp"
Jul 25 14:30:29 mail postfix/smtpd[5103]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:30:30 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5103 exit status 1
Jul 25 14:30:30 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 25 14:31:30 mail postfix/smtpd[5110]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:31:30 mail postfix/smtpd[5111]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:31:31 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5110 exit status 1
Jul 25 14:31:31 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 25 14:31:31 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5111 exit status 1
Jul 25 14:32:53 mail postfix/smtpd[5136]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:32:54 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5136 exit status 1
Jul 25 14:32:54 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 25 14:33:54 mail postfix/smtpd[5143]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:33:54 mail postfix/smtpd[5144]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:33:55 mail postfix/smtpd[5145]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:33:55 mail postfix/smtpd[5146]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
Jul 25 14:33:55 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5143 exit status 1
Jul 25 14:33:55 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 25 14:33:55 mail postfix/master[2644]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5144 exit status 1
```

This is my master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
# smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -v
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=no
#  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o receive_override_options=
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
 smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
        -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}$
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

smtp-amavis unix -      -       n     -       2  smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20


127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       n     -       -  smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0    
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_check
  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
#05.09.2016  dodao smtpd_sender_restrictions => napravio modifikaciju (dodao ko$
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipi$
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#dolje promjena u "yes" 07092016
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.gkri.hr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.gkri.hr, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 193.198.1.29
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
#inet_interfaces = all
inet_interfaces = 193.198.1.XX, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#virtual_alias_domains=gkri.hr
virtual_gid_maps = static:107
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 105
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:105

relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf

content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,check_sender_access pcre:/et$

receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
#promjena na "yes" 07092016 - red dolje
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth


#dodao nakon 5-tog reda još na smtpd_recipient_restrictions 24032017
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
#  permit_sasl_authenticated,
#  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_checks,
#  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
# 30032017 jer neki nakladnici nemaju reverse  reject_unknown_reverse_client_ho$
# reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
#  reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/exempt_senders,
 check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
  reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
#  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
 reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl,
  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
#  reject_rbl_client proxies.blackholes.wirehub.net,
  reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org
#  reject_rbl_client opm.blitzed.org,
#  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
#  reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
#  reject_rbl_client multihop.dsbl.org

  permit

message_size_limit = 104857600
virtual_mailbox_limit = 104857600
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client proxies.blackholes.wirehub.net,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client opm.blitzed.org
       # reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
#radi poteskoce kada se pokrene (oprez)
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_ac$

#trebalo bi blokirati neke att (trenutno ne radi)
#mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks

#dodatno 05.09.2016 u 14:57h
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 3
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10


#dodano 19092016 radi DKIM
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:1427143
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:1427143


#dodatno 30032017
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes

Rate throttlanje

smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 10s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
#smptd_hard_error_limit = 5

#dodatno18022019 radi vivainfo, maknuo 04072019
#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
```

Comment: Ouch...first remove the whitespace before `smtps`, postfix is picky about indentations (if you need it at all)

Comment: just did...also commented out -o receive_override_options=, now I'm getting a new error where sender address trigers amavis

Answer (score 2):

Your master.cf contains a line

```
-o receive_override_options=
```

with nothing after the `=`. Postfix expects that what follows after the `=` should be a list of command line options that you want to use.

Since the line ends there, postfix tries to use the next words it finds in the file as command line options, and that's why you're getting log errors such as

```
Jul 25 14:33:54 mail postfix/smtpd[5143]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: smtps
```

If you don't want to pass any command line arguments, you should just comment out that line in master.cf.

Comment: after commenting out -o receive_override_options=
I get
root@mail:/etc/postfix# tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep "rene.brakus@gkri.hr"
Jul 25 15:20:29 mail dovecot: auth-worker(2529): Debug: sql(rene.brakus@gkri.hr,193.198.1.11): query: SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'rene.brakus@gkri.hr' AND active = '1'
Jul 25 15:20:29 mail dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK#0112#011user=rene.brakus@gkri.hr

Comment: AND....
Jul 25 15:20:29 mail postfix/smtpd[6071]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail.gkri.hr[193.198.1.11]: <rene.brakus@gkri.hr>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025; from=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> to=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.gkri.hr>
Jul 25 15:20:30 mail postfix/smtpd[6071]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.gkri.hr[193.198.1.11]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> to=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.gkri.hr>

as an error

Comment: Jul 25 15:28:32 mail postfix/smtpd[6167]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jul 25 15:28:33 mail postfix/smtpd[6167]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jul 25 15:28:33 mail postfix/smtpd[6167]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jul 25 15:28:33 mail postfix/smtpd[6167]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.gkri.hr[193.198.1.11]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> to=<rene.brakus@gkri.hr> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.gkri.hr>